# Difference between replace_NaN and replace_Na show unexpected outcome

Tags: r

The function is

```
myfun <- function(replace_NaN = NULL) {if(replace_NaN == 1) message("Why print this")}
```

**Try 1:**

```
myfun(replace_Nk = 1)
```

Output: Error in myfun(replace_Nk = 1) : unused argument (replace_Nk = 1)

Comment: Error as expected

**Try 2:**

```
myfun(replace_NaN= 1)
```

Output: Why print this

Comment: Output as expected

**Try 3:**

```
myfun(replace_Na= 1)
```

Output: Why print this

Comment: I was expecting an error like as try 1. But why this has executed!!

I will be thankful if anyone knows how to solve this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

R does partial matching of arguments. Here it works because `replace_Na` is part of `replace_NaN` which is your original argument name.

If you change that to `myfun(replace_Nb= 1)` you get an error

> Error in myfun(replace_Nb = 1) : unused argument (replace_Nb = 1)

because `replace_Nb` is not part of `replace_NaN`.

The reason why this is in place is to avoid typing long argument names which is sometimes convenient but can be confusing and give unexpected result at other times.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But isn't it some kind of bug !!

Comment: It depends how you take it, it can be also called as a feature ;-). Anyway, you can read more about it here if interested https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching